# Does comfrey make a great garden perimeter?

Tags: pest-control, comfrey

I'm into the no till side of gardening, and have heard that comfrey "grows in place". Would comfrey make a great garden perimeter plant to keep animals out by feeding them better food than the stuff in the middle of the garden?